# jQuery select2 breaks as soon as I add tags

Tags: jquery, tags, jquery-select2

As soon as I add tags to my jQuery `select2` it breaks and reverts back to the normal HTML `select` box.

Here is my code (exactly like [this example](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tags").select2({tags:["red", "green", "blue"]});
});
```

If I remove the tags part it works again:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tags").select2();
});
```

Comment: What is `#tags` a `<div>` or a `<select>` - it wont work for `<select>`

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/2Xt2u/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you look in your javascript console you will see the following error message:

> Error: Option 'tags' is not allowed for Select2 when attached to a
>   `<select>` element.

That means, when you want to use the 'tags' option, you have to apply it to an `input:text` element instead of a `select`.

JSFiddle with proof: http://jsfiddle.net/Y8Wc7/

Answer (score 8):

Select2 [version 4.0.0](https://select2.github.io/examples.html) now allows tags to be attached to a `<select>`

Comment: I am using select2 v4.0+ but still facing the same issue.

Comment: Take a look at https://select2.org/tagging