# Tagging text in jquery select2

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-select2

```
<select multiple id="e1" style="width:300px">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
        <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
        <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>

$("#e1").select2({'placeholder': ' ','allowClear': true});
```

it is working fine for matched text. But i want to tag text(which doesnot match any option).
Kindly help.

please find the demo code in following link.
http://jsfiddle.net/marcusasplund/jEADR/2/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select2 with createSearchChoice uses newly created choice for keyboard entry even given a match, bug or am I missing something?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16606092/select2-with-createsearchchoice-uses-newly-created-choice-for-keyboard-entry-eve)

Comment: You are using **an incredibly old** (_nearly three years old_) version of Select2. **Please update**, we will all thank you later.

Answer (score 4):

You have the tags option, but it can't be used with `select` element

```js
$("#e1").select2({
  tags: [{
    "id": "AL",
    "text": "Alabama"
  }, {
    "id": "Am",
    "text": "Amalapuram"
  }, {
    "id": "An",
    "text": "Anakapalli"
  }, {
    "id": "Ak",
    "text": "Akkayapalem"
  }, {
    "id": "WY",
    "text": "Wyoming"
  }]
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.2/select2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.2/select2.css"/>

<input id="e1" style="width:300px" />
```

Comment: how can i add objects to tags array dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

There is an option called `tags` in `select2` which allows you to unmatched text to `tags` but there are some problems here.

- It will not allow you to set `tags` option if you are binding `select2`  plugin on `select`. So for this you need to bind `select2` on `input`.

<kbd>**[SOURCE QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24146954/jquery-select2-breaks-as-soon-as-i-add-tags)**</kbd>

- `Select2` Version `4.0` allows you to add `tags` option to `select` control too.

> **So the solution is either you need to upgrade to the latest plugin or
>   you need to bind `select2` on `input` control.**